# Is allocating user creation to user model instead of user controller bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, omniauth

In a standard Rails application with omniauth, is it bad practice to allocate the creation of a User to the User model (user.rb) rather than to the Users controller (users_controller.rb)? It doesn't seem RESTful, but I've seen it done in conjunction with omniauth in several Railscasts, e.g. http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user model should create the new user, however a controller should be what kicks off that process. The user shouldn't just be magically created out of thin air. Something at the controller layer triggers the creation of the user, be it logging in to the application, a controller filter, or a straight up call to your UsersController via a `POST /users/create`.